# Filter or distinguish built-in and custom graphql types

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, introspection

I'm trying to find a way to distinguish (and filter out) the built-in types from my custom types when running an introspectionQuery against a graphql api. There doesn't seem to be anything reliable in the output to identify which types are built-in (apart from the __ in front of the "system" types).

At this point I can't even seem to find a single official list, so my best option seems to be to go over the introspectionQuery output and make a list for future use, hoping nothing changes.

Are the really no systematic way to distinguish the two?

Comment: Did you ever find a query to do this?

Comment: @pkatsourakis unfortunately not. But as the answer below states they are pretty straight forward and unlikely to change :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isIntrospectionType` function:

```
import { buildSchema, isIntrospectionType } from 'graphql';


const schema = buildSchema(source);

for (const type of Object.values(schema.getTypeMap())) {
  if (isIntrospectionType(type)) continue;

  // do something...
}
```

**PS.** You can use `isSpecifiedScalarType` as well to filter Scalar nodes such as `ID`, `Int`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

While the spec *does* specify scalar types that every implementation should include and specifies how these scalars should be serialized and parsed, it doesn't really draw a distinction between these built-in scalars and any others a GraphQL service might expose. Functionally, there is no difference between a "built-in" type and a "custom" one.

There are five built-in scalars [outlined by the spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Scalars). These are very unlikely to change in the future.

- Int
- Float
- String
- Boolean
- ID

There are also several "meta" types that are used explicitly for introspection. These are outlined [here](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Schema-Introspection).

- __Schema
- __Type
- __Field
- __InputValue
- __EnumValue
- __TypeKind
- __Directive
- __DirectiveLocation

Names beginning with two underscores (`__`) are reserved names, so any types with names beginning in this way can safely be classified as "built-in".

It's unclear from your question to what end you are trying to draw the distinction between "built-in" and "custom" types, but I would guess for most purposes we would consider the above to be the "built-in" types and any others "custom".

Comment: My use case at hand is a reusable test setup, where I iterate over the types returned by the introspection query (provided by the `graphql`npm module) and check for stuff like description. It is also useful in scenarios like generating documentation for an API or building an introspective data browser. Thanks for the links, I'll just go by the spec :)